# Bulk delete/edit excerpts in Wordpress?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I've taken over and built a new theme utilizing all the goodies Wordpress comes with. I'm also using the built-in excerpts functions within Wordpress... however, the previous user wasn't using automatic excerpts and was manually typing their own excerpts.

I was wondering if there is a method to either override the manual excerpts or to perform a bulk edit on the excerpts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the query

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_excerpt=''
```

in phpmyadmin. Change the table prefix in the query if the default prefix of `wp_` isn't being used. **Backup your database first.**

Or:

If you don't want to use phpmyadmin, run the MySQL query as a `$wpdb` PHP function.

Put this at the bottom (or top) of your functions.php file and reload the site:

```
$wpdb->query( "UPDATE wp_posts SET post_excerpt='' " );
```

Or put this in a template file, like index.php, and reload the page:

```
<?php $wpdb->query( "UPDATE wp_posts SET post_excerpt='' " ); ?>
```

***And of course, remove either of those PHP functions from the file after you run them.***

***Edit: and, it's a good idea to select for the post type of posts when using the query, as Murilo Pontes in his answer; otherwise, plugins and other functions that may use the excerpt for data storage will lose their data.***

Comment: Is there anyway, without having to access PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: Just as an update to this, you can also run this using WP CLI - `wp db query "UPDATE wp_posts SET post_excerpt='' "`

Comment: Be carefull with this. It seem that also delete custom field name with ACF... Maybe not the best solution.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use "UPDATE wp_posts SET post_excerpt='' ". That can break things (like email templates) if post_type is not configured
Use the following querys instead.

View excerpts
SELECT `post_excerpt` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type`='post'

Update excerpts to ''
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_excerpt=''  WHERE `post_type`='post'